# Self and numberOfInSections

Tags: swift, tableview, uitableview

The other errors have been fixed, but now I am getting another unresolved identifier at "let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController"

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "meunSegue", sender: self)

        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    }
}
    let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var recievedData = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(recievedData)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where did you defined numberRowsOfInSection in your class? return number of rows that you wanted(Int value) and you have ended the class scope after numberOfRowsInSection method. end it after preparemethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `numberOfRowsInSection` you need to return the number of rows count, currently you are returning `numberRowsOfInSection` but there is no declaration of `numberRowsOfInSection` in your `ViewController`. So return the number of rows count that you want with your `tableView`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 5
}
```

Also with `cellForRowAt` you are returning `UITableViewCell()` empty cell so you can't see in tableView instead of that `dequeue` the cell and then set the label text that you want and return the cell.

**Note:** In your code you have added `didSelectRowAt` and `prepareForSegue` method outside your class, you need to add that inside your class.

Comment: Thanks but now I have another unresolved identifier "segue" at let secondViewController

Comment: @Alexis Add that line inside the `prepareForSegue` method. Also add `override` prefix with `prepareForSegue` method/